# Three SELECT and two jsons

Tags: php, mysql, json

I created a SELECT to get my communities.

And create two SELECTs to get the communities I'm following.

But I get just my communities.

I do not get the communities I'm following.

```
$user_id = $_GET["id"];

$row1 = array();
$row2 = array();

// get my communities

$res1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM communities where user_id = '$user_id'");

while($r1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res1)) {
$row1[] = $r1;
   }

// get "id" of my communities I'm following 

$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM communities_follow where user_id = '$user_id'");

while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $coid = $r["coid"];

// get my communities I'm following 

$res2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM communities where id = '$coid'");

while($r2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res2)) {
$row2[] = $r2;
   }


   }       

 $resp = array_replace_recursive($row1, $row2);

 print json_encode( $resp );
```

Comment: You should not use `mysql_query` anymore. Switch to `mysqli_query` or use PDO instead. See here: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

Comment: Your query *should* work nonetheless, *if* you are addressing the *right columns* in it with your where clause. Maybe you can add the table structure or some sample data to clarify. In each case the PHP loop should be avoided since it will always be slower than the direct query mentioned in the answers below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inner join will get you those communities only, where you are following:

```
SELECT c.* FROM communities c 
INNER JOIN communities_follow cf ON c.id = cf.coid
WHERE cf.user_id = '$user_id';
```

Or, without a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT * FROM communities
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM communities_follow cf
  WHERE c.id = cf.coid AND cf.user_id = '$user_id')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this sql.

```
SELECT * FROM communities c LEFT JOIN communities_follow cf ON c.user_id = cf.user_id where
cf.user_id = '$user_id';
```